# How to make button background transparent?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2012

I have created one button and applied image (.png with transparent background) on it.
[image]
My button background is set on transparent but as you can see the background color is still there.
How can I make this work as it should?

Comment: Are you using WinForms, WPF, or something else?

Comment: @Zairja I am using
 WinForms, sorry will add tag

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Give this a shot.

```
'Making Existing Button Transparent
btnKasa.FlatStyle = Windows.Forms.FlatStyle.Flat
btnKasa.FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 0
btnKasa.FlatAppearance.MouseDownBackColor = Color.Transparent
btnKasa.FlatAppearance.MouseOverBackColor = Color.Transparent
btnKasa.BackColor = Color.Transparent
```

Comment: This can also be done through the property sheet. +1 for giving the properties I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Another option that I came up with is to call:

`SetStyle(ControlStyles.SupportsTransparentBackColor, True)`

when the form is created (e.g. in the constructor after `InitializeComponent()`). The button's `BackColor` is set to Transparent, as well (this can be done in code behind or in the properties).

Comment: This could be a solution also, but that just make all button background in form to be transparent. +1 anyway