# How to handle MouseHover and MouseLeave events in a IconButton VB .NET WinForm

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, button, mouseevent

I have a VB .NET WinForm with a Home Button (*btnHome*) inside of it.

How to handle **MouseHover** and **MouseLeave** events in FontAwesome IconButton?

I tried the following but it didn't work:

```
    Private Sub btnHome_MouseHover(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnHome.MouseHover
        Me.btnHome.BackColor = Color.Black
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnHome_MouseLeave(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnHome.MouseLeave
        Me.btnHome.BackColor = Color.Transparent
    End Sub
```

A transition to a light color appears at the button before reaching black.

On the other hand, the previous code worked for a common Windows Form Button from the Tool Box.

I tried other two events too without success:

- Enter
- Move

What I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you creating the btnHome at design time or runtime?

Comment: The `HoverColor` and `NormalColor` are defined in the Button's constructor. After that, you can set the `ActiveColor` (hover) and `InActiveColor` (normal). These Colors are used to paint the Icon background.

Comment: I get that light color going to black with a regular button. It disappears if I use the Enter event.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me in C#. Note that Transparent is not officially supported as a background color in buttons. Other colors will work however (I used green). You should also set the BackColor to be the same as in the MouseLeave event in the constructor after the InitializeComponent() line.

```
private void btnHome_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    btnHome.BackColor = Color.Black;
}

private void btnHome_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    btnHome.BackColor = Color.Green;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

"Transparent is not officially supported as a background color in buttons" from Kim answer helped me to arrive to this question: [How to make button background transparent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27628216/how-to-make-button-background-transparent)
.

From there, I managed to solve it as follows:

```
        With btnHome.FlatAppearance
            .MouseOverBackColor = Color.FromArgb(125, RGBColors.color1)
            .MouseDownBackColor = Color.Transparent
        End With
```

FlatAppearance was the Property I was looking for.

Thank you all.